# In RubyZoho, how to set Task.related_to Lead.id?

Tags: ruby, zoho

I wrote this question up at RubyZoho's forum, but it's languishing there, and it's such a simple question it deserves a wider audience.

I have used RubyZoho to upload a new Lead record to the Zoho CRM API, and now I want to upload a Task with its "related to" field set to that Lead.

Configuring RubyZoho:

```
RubyZoho.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = Setting.plugin_redmine_tigase['zoho_authorization_token']
  config.crm_modules = [
      'Leads',
      'Tasks'
  ]
  config.ignore_fields_with_bad_names = true
  config.cache_fields = true
end
```

Creating the lead:

```
  lead = RubyZoho::Crm::Lead.new
  lead.first_name = splut.first
  lead.last_name = splut.last
  lead.full_name = params[:name]
  lead.company = params[:company]
  lead.email = params[:mail]
  lead.description = description
  lead.save
```

Creating the Task:

```
  found = RubyZoho::Crm::Lead.find_by_email(params[:mail])
  lead = found.first
  task = RubyZoho::Crm::Task.new
  task.related_to = lead.id
  task.subject = params[:subject]
  task.description = description
  task.save
```

I tried `task.related_to = lead.leadid`, and got a Task record with a blank "related to" in the Zoho website. And when I try `task.related_to = 'Lead'; task.relatedtoid = lead.leadid`, I get a `undefined method relatedtoid=`, naturally because the variable has no setter.

So what am I missing? how do I do this simple thing?

Comment: Can you post your `RubyZoho.configure ` block code?

Comment: And the code where you're actually creating the task?

Comment: They are trivial but I added them.

Comment: Seems obvious, but are we're sure `lead.id` returns a value? do both `lead.save` and `task.save` work?  is it possible that `lead = found.first; lead == nil` ?

Comment: Both `lead.save` and `task.save` are working because I can find the records they wrote in Zoho. `lead` is not `nil`, and `lead.id` is `3209647000000176001`. Still no link between the records.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation it has a section on this

https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/script/creating-a-record-in-zoho-crm.html#create-lead

```
taskInfo = {
"Task Owner" : input.Owner_Name,
"SMOWNERID" : input.Owner_ID,
"Subject" : input.Subject,
"Description" : input.Description,
"SEMODULE" : "Accounts",
"SEID" : input.Account_ID,
"CONTACTID" : input.Contact_ID};
crmResp = zoho.crm.create("Tasks", taskInfo);
```

> SMOWNERID is the ID of the Owner
>
> SEMODULE can be Accounts or Leads or Cases
>
> SEID is the ID of the Record given in the SEMODULE
>
> CONTACTID is the ID of the contact record

Also if you look at the `ruby_zoho_rspec` for creating new task

https://github.com/amalc/rubyzoho/blob/950ffe369252f8fad3e7ae67ebddec859c84e19b/spec/ruby_zoho_spec.rb

```
it 'should save an task record related to an account' do
VCR.use_cassette 'zoho/task_related_to_account' do
  a = RubyZoho::Crm::Account.all.first
  e = RubyZoho::Crm::Task.new(
      :task_owner => a.account_owner,
      :subject => "Task should be related to #{a.account_name} #{Time.now}",
      :description => 'Nothing',
      :smownerid => "#{a.smownerid}",
      :status => 'Not Started',
      :priority => 'High',
      :send_notification_email => 'False',
      :due_date => '2014-02-16 16:00:00',
      :start_datetime => Time.now.to_s[1, 19],
      :end_datetime => '2014-02-16 16:00:00',
      :related_to => "#{a.account_name}",
      :seid => "#{a.accountid}",
      :semodule => 'Accounts'
  )
  r_expected = e.save
  r = RubyZoho::Crm::Task.find_by_activityid(r_expected.id)
  r.first.subject[0..20].should eq(r_expected.subject[0..20])
end
```

So that should help you out link it by specifying `SEMODULE` and `SEID`

Comment: It wasn't me. But I'm still processing your answer; I have a higher-priority task now

Comment: @Phlip, no worries. Just do it a timely manner, so in case it doesn't work we can look at other possibilities.